# Installing Server 2008 on one PC and Windows 7 on another PC

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008

I want to install Windows Server 2008. Is installation similar to other Windows operating systems? Can I use my personal computer after this installation as a server and my friend's computer as a client?

I want to Utilize Active Directory, DHCP, DNS and FTP along with other tasks.

Is it possible to create a local account on a Server 2008 installation?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server installs are very similar to client installs. The primary difference is that you will be asked if you want "Server Core" or full "GUI."

For the full desktop experience, you will want full "GUI." You can indeed use another computer as a client. If you wish to use active directory, you will need to install the "Active directory Domain Services" role from the server manager.

For DHCP you want the "DHCP Server" role and for DNS you will want the "DNS Server role". FTP is a role underneath "IIS Webservice" I believe.

You can indeed use local accounts on a server. using the Local users and group Microsoft Management Console snap-in.

I am guessing that this is for educational purposes? If so I would suggest running the server as a virtual machine on your computer (Hyper-V, Virtualbox, Vmware workstation etc) Note you will need a computer with a compatable CPU (each hypervisor will list its requirements.)

I would recommend that you do not store live data on these systems, with a single domain controller if it goes down, you loose everything.

Going into any more detail would neccessitate full guides for each of the above topics. I would recommend considering looking at the microsoft MCSE for windows server or similar program (Even just tutorials on the internet!) to help you gain the knowledge required.

Comment: OK! i tray it but during installation on virtual machine  machine server 2008 notify the following message LIKE indicate their is enable or disable something on BIOS how can i solve this?

Comment: @Ephrem What hypervisor are you using to run the virtual machine? Usually your motherboard needs to support Intel VT-x, 64 bit processor with SLAT, 4GB ram and there is usually a generic virtualization option in the bios. If your happy to share what your motherboard & processor is, I can check if they are compatable

Comment: @Lster. am using window 7 64 bit operating system and 4 gb ram hp computer.   i installing 32 bit window on vertual machine but server can't install and state the problem that i tell u befor. pentium(r) dual core cpu so what shall i do lister?

Comment: You need to be more specific, what is the exact model number of the Pentium? There are literally generations of them. If you can also give me the model name of the HP computer that should let me check the motherboard. Also when I say hyper visor I mean are you using hyper-v, beware virtual box etc.

Comment: @L. its done that is the matter of compatibility.i use vertual box 4.2.222 it works. but it says network cable unplugged server 2003. how can i solve this problem?

Comment: In the virtual box settings for the virtual machine you will need to set up the virtual network card. I would suggest reading the guides to see which type of virtual network is suitable for you.